# What happend to the favorite tab bottom line?

Tags: bug, design

There is a missing line on the bottom of the *favorites* tab.

[image: Missing bottom line]

I only expect this, if the tab is  active.

<sub>FF 61.0.1 (64-Bit) @ Win10 @1080p</sub>

Comment: is browser zoom at default 100%?

Comment: yes @SamuelLiew

Comment: Looking good in FF 60.0.2 (64-Bit) @ Win10 @ 1080p